# goshippo create order via api

Tags: api, orders, shippo

I'm trying to figure out a way to create orders via API (the ones that show up under https://app.goshippo.com/orders/), but seems like api docs dont really explain how to do so, and the only thing thats available is to create shipping labels. The libraries dont have any functions that will point me to this direction either. Is it even possible to make a call to the api for orders ? 
Also, if this is not possible, how can I make goShippo send me a request for lets say a CSV, to sync all orders ?

PS: this is a custom build

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Feel free to use our order endpoint `/v1/orders`, but it is currently in beta version. The behavior of this endpoint may change (fields, error messages). We will update the following gist according to any modification that we make.**

You can find more details about the endpoint at https://goshippo.com/docs/orders

The following Gist shows you how to POST on the Order endpoint.

https://gist.github.com/mnowik/59d2d550107b77cb31bf79b6b75d6e27

Fields with `*` are not active yet.